# How to add Multiple file fields in Oracle UCM Content Profile?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-ucm

I am kind of new to `Oracle UCM`, I am working on One Project where I am supposed to add multiple file fields to upload multiple files other than primary and alternate file.

Is there a possible way to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking how to add custom metadata fields or attach a file to an uploaded file? or upload multiple files in addition to the main file? If the last, then you would need a custom component to do this as UCM OOTB won't do this. Also, when posting questions on vendor, always include product version number and OS - help us help you.

Comment: thankyou joe for the answer, well i am asking about the custom metadata fields in the profile. and sorry I forgot to add the version number and OS, Version is 11.1.XX and the OS is linux.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Oracle WebCenter Content (formerly Oracle UCM) gives you two fields (primary file and alternate file).

There are other components, such as *ZipRenditionManagement*, which allow you to add additional renditions to the same content item (with the same metadata) (e.g. IdcService=EDIT_RENDITIONS_FORM&dID=1208&dDocName=DEV000839&dDocTitle=Test).

There is also the [*RelatedContent*](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcc/WCCAA/GUID-6CF263BB-58E9-4A12-A309-AE28C70BC578.htm) component which creates separate content items (with their own metadata) and allows you to link these content items together.

Comment: thankyou for the reply Jonathan, I will try to do as your said and will reply here. PS: I follow your blog on web center and it is of great help!